# How to expand extra space to an already burnt flash drive with Ubuntu 13.10, so that I can save all changes I have made when using it

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB disk with a bootable Ubuntu inside, there must be some missteps have been made when I making it with help of Universal USB installer, which lead to all saved documents or newly installed applications lost every time I boot from it again.

I won't be willing to burn a new bootable flash drive, what're some elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would take only a few minutes (including 2-3 minutes to make the Ubuntu live USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or Universal USB Installer) to reformat the flash drive as FAT32 and then rewrite the Ubuntu iso to it using Universal USB Installer, this time making sure to give the Ubuntu live USB enough space for persistent storing of changes by moving the slider marked by a black arrow in the below screenshot.

This is not the way you asked to do it, but it's probably the fastest way to do it. If you have another flash drive with some other live USB on it, such as Clonezilla or GParted, it's also the easiest way to update the live USB to the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I just know what to do if I want to do it from the very beginning.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You asked for X and I answered Y, but X takes too long to do and Y takes 2-3 minutes the way I do it, so I answered it like it was an XY problem (which is  an entirely subjective description) anyway.